# How to union polygons in PySpark using UDF

Tags: pyspark, gis, geojson, shapely

The polygon data I use is stored as a GeoJSON-type in list.
I want to union polygons in a list.

Example data:

| ID | Polygons | Count polygons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[129.1012158, 35.2478918], ......}] | 3 |
| 2 | [{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[129.1012158, 35.2478918], ......}] | 2 |

Expected data:

| ID | union_polygons |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[129.1012158, 35.2478918], ......}] |
| 2 | {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[129.1012158, 35.2478918], ......}] |

Code:

```
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union, unary_union
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point, Polygon, mapping
from json import load, JSONEncoder
import shapely

@F.udf(StringType())
def union_polygons(polygon_column):
    a = unary_union([shape(json.loads(p)) for p in polygons])
    b = json.dumps(shapely.geometry.mapping(a))
    return b


df.withColumn('union_polygon', union_polygons('polygons')).show()
```

When testing with the code above, the following error occurs:

```
Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle LGEOS360 objects
...
...
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle LGEOS360 objects
```

I want to union the GeoJSON contained in the list column through UDF. How can I do this?

Comment: what is the data type of `b` in the original function?

Comment: An error occurs in the process of unary union. Before that, the list type is `net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor@40980130`

Answer (score 2):

There is a small error in the definition of the udf: when calculating `a` you should iterate over the list that is returned by `json.loads(p)`:

```python
@F.udf(StringType())
def union_polygons(polygon_column):
    a = shapely.ops.unary_union([shape(p) for p in json.loads(polygon_column)])
    b = json.dumps(shapely.geometry.mapping(a))
    return b
```

Comment: Thanks, It was not solved by this method because there are several jsons in the list, but it was solved by using shapely.ops.unary_union instead of unary_union.